# firefox extension javascript storage

Tags: javascript, firefox, storage

I want to program a firefox formfiller extension. What I don't quite understand is how do I save my content. To a sqllite file or are there other ways to do it and how would the javascript code look like?

cheers, US

Comment: You could save strings as a setting using `localStorage`.

Answer (score 2):

First result for "[extension storage javascript](http://www.google.it/search?q=extension+storage+javascript&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3ait%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)": https://developer.mozilla.org/en/storage (see also the first note on that page)